# No option for R scripts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r

I want to use R in QGIS but I'm unable to find any sign of `"R"` in `Processing  > Processing Toolbox > Options`.

How can I install or maybe add R in QGIS? I dont know what this process is called, I'm new in R and QGIS software.

Comment: Which QGIS version is that? Have you added a folder as a `Scripts folder` via `Options > Processing > Scripts`? Check this topic [Link R and QGIS: Integrate your own R algorithms in QGIS](https://www.aspexit.com/en/link-r-and-qgis-integrate-your-own-r-algorithms-in-qgis/)